# Using Curly Brackets in xpath - Selenium - Beginner

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Selenium and want to identify an element via xpath. The locator I want to use looks like this:

```
ref_code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-eui-handler="{ event:'click',handler: 'eui.app.controller.search_results.selectRow' }"]/td[1]")
```

This ends in a syntax error because as far as I see "event" and "handler" in the string are key words. How can I change it, so it is all seen as a string?

I believe the curly brackets are ending the string format right?

Sorry, I am new to this :)

Thanks
Pat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the brackets but the `"`

Use

```
ref_code = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-eui-handler=\"event:'click',handler:'eui.app.controller.search_results.selectRow'}\"]/td[1]")
```

You need to put an `\` before `"` if they are part of the string